# Can't send mp4 file to folder

Tags: java, php, android

I would like to send a MP4 file from my Android, to a folder on my computer, using HTTP.

I already created my MP4 file, and I guess that the Java code is working well because I'm not receiving any error.

The issue here must be the PHP, because the script doesn't receive the file, everytime I test my code, fails.

I searched on the Internet and I found this code here for the Java:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

public class FileUploader {

        URL connectURL;
        String responseString;
        String Title;
        String Description;
        byte[ ] dataToServer;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

        public FileUploader(String urlString, String vTitle, String vDesc){
            try{
                connectURL = new URL(urlString);
                Title= vTitle;
                Description = vDesc;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.i("HttpFileUpload","URL Malformatted");
            }
        }

        public void Send_Now(FileInputStream fStream){
            fileInputStream = fStream;
            Sending();
        }

        public void Sending(){

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            String iFileName = "bu.mp4";
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            String Tag="fSnd";
            try
            {
                Log.e(Tag,"Starting Http File Sending to URL");

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();

                // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                // Allow Outputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                // Don't use a cached copy.
                conn.setUseCaches(false);

                // Use a post method.
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\""+ lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(Title);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\""+ lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(Description);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + iFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                Log.e(Tag,"Headers are written");
                // create a buffer of maximum size
                int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                int maxBufferSize = 1024;
                int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                byte[ ] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,bufferSize);
                }
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // close streams
                fileInputStream.close();

                dos.flush();

                Log.e(Tag,"File Sent, Response: "+String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));

                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                // retrieve the response from server
                int ch;

                StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();
                while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){ b.append( (char)ch ); }
                String s=b.toString();
                Log.i("Response",s);
                dos.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException ex)
            {
                Log.e(Tag, "URL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }

            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                Log.e(Tag, "IO error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            }
        }


    }
```

I'm calling this class using the following code:

```
public static void UploadFile(){
    try {

        // Set your file path here
        FileInputStream fstrm = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
                + "sound" + "/bu.mp4");


        // Set your server page url (and the file title/description)
        FileUploader hfu = new FileUploader("http:/****/uploads/go.php", "title","test");

        hfu.Send_Now(fstrm);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Error: File not found

        Log.e("error", "oh lord");

    }
```

}

And I'm using the following code in PHP to receive the file:

```
//start upload
$file_path = "teste/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

Can you guys help me? Thank you!

Comment: `uploadedfile` != `uploaded_file`

Comment: Omg, you are right, thank you so much, I lost 2 hours here